# Make ranking system based on average and total reviews

Tags: php, variables, ranking

I tried to make the title as logical as possible. I have a review system and I stumble over the fact that I want to make a fair ranking. I want to create a number that is based on the average review score and the number of reviews that are submitted.

For example, I got Company A and Company B.

Company A has an average score of 4.8 based on 5 reviews.
Company B has an average score of 4.7 based on 43 reviews.

If you rank on average score Company A is above Company B in ranking but I think it ain't fair because it is a lot harder to get a 4.7 based on 43 reviews.

Maybe this is not a coding question but how can I create a number that somehow calculates the data and ranks Company B above Company A because it is harder to get 4.7 based on 43 reviews than 4.8 based on 5 reviews.

I got both values stored in a variable:

```
$average_score;
$count_reviews;
```

I tried something like this:

```
$average_total = $average_score * $count_reviews/ 100;
```

But maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: While not code related, perhaps this could help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942738/algorithm-to-calculate-rating-based-on-multiple-reviews-using-both-review-score

Comment: @Matthew thanks, just took a look at it and it is more complex that I tought but wil give it a shot

Comment: It can also make sense to involve a logarithm function (log₂, ln) in instances like this. The gradually ascending curves of those make it easier to put more emphasis on smaller numbers - like the difference between two averages based 3 and 5 reviews respectively, is probably more important, than that between two that are based on 103 and 105 reviews.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I will search a bit more because this is not something I can manage to get working with my mathmatic skills ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Try to do this math:**

`$average_total = ($count_reviews/5)/($count_reviews/$average_score)*($count_reviews);`

***I know your using `PHP`, but for demonstration purposes I have to use `Javascript`.***

```js
var reviews = {
  "companyA":["4.8", "5"], //[$average_score,$count_reviews]
  "companyB":["4.7", "43"],
  "companyC":["4.5", "70"],
  "companyD":["4.8", "1"],
};

var order = [];

for (var company in reviews) {
var mathstmt = (reviews[company][1]/5)/(reviews[company][1]/reviews[company][0])*(reviews[company][1]);
    order.push([company, mathstmt]);
}

order.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
}).reverse();

for(var x = 0;x<order.length;x++){
  console.log(order[x][0]);
}
```

**I'm sorry if this `javascript` seems complicated, but I want you to try the math yourself.**

Comment: thank you very much. I will try it with the Javascript you provided. If I run into any problems, can I ask you?

Comment: @user2812779 Your welcome to ask whatever you want ;). Also I provided a simple math for `php` which is this : `$average_total = $count_reviews/$average_score;` you can also use it in your `php` and it should work fine.

Comment: $average_total = $count_reviews/$average_score; is not working because the $average_total is the number I am sorting on from high to low. And to give you one example: Company A: 5/3.4 = 1.4705882352941 and Company B: 7/4.9 = 1.4285714285714. So if you look at the outcome Company A is ranked over Company B but the score of Company B is way better.

Comment: Ohw and this javascript is also doing the sorting. But the sorting part from high to low I allready got working. I need to generate somekind of number with the variables I got. Your Javascript function is working exactly how it should based on my input. But I need a number where I can make the sorting on based on the two variables I got. is this possible you think?

Comment: @user2812779 I'm sorry my math was incorrect, I updated the answer now it should work fine.

Comment: thank you for the update. i tried it and this is better then the formula you provided before but still not complete I think. I think the math is correct but for some reason if you compare some ranking results in my opinion it is not fair. For example what is happening now: Company A has a score of 4.2 based on 8 reviews and a calculated number of 6.72. Company B has a score of 4.9 based on 6 reviews and a calulated number of 5.88. So Company A is ranked above Company B and if you ask my opnion a 4.9 based on 6 reviews is better. But I think this is more difficult then I tought